# Trouble starting JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss

I recently installed JBOSS on a test server to do some work on. Everything seems set correctly and my java home is set to:

```
JAVA_HOME = c:\Java\jdk1.6.0_16
```

When I start it locally on the command prompt using the command:

```
run -b 0.0.0.0 -c sd
```

it prints out:

```
Calling C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\run.conf.bat
```

and then returns to the cursor. It seems to crash almost instantly with no error and nothing reported in the log.

If I delete the `run.conf.bat` file it states that the file is missing but tries to execute anyway without it. So when the `.bat` file is there it crashes instantly. When it isn't there it actually tries to run and goes through the motions. Any ideas?

To clarify I do not get any error messages whatsoever. It just crashes.

Comment: Have you made any changes to `run.conf.bat`? Where are you setting JAVA_HOME (My Computer-> Properties-> Environment variables, or command line), and have you set JBOSS_HOME?

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how it crashes? You say there is no error (even not in boot.log i guess). So does it terminate to console? Or freeze?

Comment: Rajesh, I took a look at the the environmental settings of the .bat file and sure enough it was setting it to some Java path that did not exist for some reason. I corrected it and it worked. Thanks for the help!